# PHPExcel. How to check if current cell is merged with another?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I use PHPExcel to import Excel files to my site. For example, there is two cells, A1 and A2, both merged. Is there a way to to find out is A1 merged to another cell (A2 or other) or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$workbook = new PHPExcel;
$sheet = $workbook->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->mergeCells('A1:E1');

$cell = $sheet->getCell('A1');

// Check if cell is merged
foreach ($sheet->getMergeCells() as $cells) {
    if ($cell->isInRange($cells)) {
        echo 'Cell is merged!'
        break;
    }
}
```

I think there isn't better solution because of the way phpexcel stores information about merged cells.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I hope you don't mind, but I've expanded it with another example of how to also get the master cell value if the cell you're querying is part of a merged range. (Because this is what I was searching for an answer for)

Comment: How do i get A1:E1 if isInRange() is true?

Comment: It's `$cell` afair

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the [`getMergeRange()`](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/classes/PhpOffice-PhpSpreadsheet-Cell-Cell.html#method_getMergeRange) method.

```
if ($cell->getMergeRange()) {
    // cell is merged
}
```

I suspect many people will want to know the value of the merged cell, in which case you can refer to the following code:

```
if (($range = $cell->getMergeRange()) && !$cell->isMergeRangeValueCell()) {
    $first_in_range_coordinates = strtok($range, ':');
    $value = $sheet->getCell($first_in_range_coordinates)->getValue();
}
```