# How detect is cell merged using PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpexcel, spreadsheet

Using PhpSpreadsheet, 
when I read data from the xls table, I need to find out whether this cell is merged with others, 
if yes, then do certain actions with it, if not, then do nothing

at the moment I thought of only checking for the presence of empty array elements after the text cell, but this solution is not quite universal ...

```
...
$inputFileName = $_FILES['uploadfile']["tmp_name"];
echo 'TMP-FILE-NAME: ' . $inputFileName;

$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($inputFileName); //create new speedsheen object
$loadedSheetNames = $spreadsheet->getSheetNames(); //get name of Sheet

//and than print it
    //get Sheet Name
foreach ($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {

  $sheet = $spreadsheet->getSheet($sheetIndex);
  echo "<table border=\"1\">";
  $rows = $sheet->toArray();
   **$mergeCell = $sheet->getMergeCells(); // - This is the answer to my question**
foreach ($rows AS $row) {
echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row AS $cell) {
        echo "<td>" . $cell . "</td>";
    }

    }
     echo '<br/>';
}
 echo "</table>";
```

Comment: You can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7299859/6351894

Comment: This is anothe docs about isInRange for PhpSpreadsheet, please try: https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/1.2.0/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Cell.html#method_isInRange

Comment: getMergeCells here : https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/1.2.0/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Worksheet.html#method_getMergeCells

Comment: Thank you very much, I reright code and use Your 3d answer - it perfect work

Comment: @Ngoc Nam plese wrote your therd variant as answer & I will mark it

Comment: @Artem-lv, I posted the answer. If it were not clear, please tell me for fixing it. ^.^V. Thank you for marking my answer! ^.^V

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHPExcel. How to check if current cell is merged with another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299756/phpexcel-how-to-check-if-current-cell-is-merged-with-another)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to check the cell was merged or not

1. First, you can use [getMergeCells](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/1.2.0/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Worksheet.html#method_getMergeCells) function to get all merged cells.
2. Then do loop in that cells list to check your cell is in or is not in that list.

**Summarize**: You can use this function to check cell merged or not

```php
// Check cell is merged or not
function checkMergedCell($sheet, $cell){
    foreach ($sheet->getMergeCells() as $cells) {
        if ($cell->isInRange($cells)) {
            // Cell is merged!
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The code was referenced from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7299859/6351894)

For PhpSpreadSheet:

- getMergeCells: https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/1.2.0/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Worksheet.html#method_getMergeCells
- isInRange: https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/1.2.0/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Cell.html#method_isInRange